# Vote to close! I will delete the question right away, I'm sorry. Please, can someone tell me what not to do next time?

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501883/i-seek-a-word-for-the-expectation-that-a-group-of-people-exhibit-a-singular-sta). I followed the requirements, I thought. Thanks for any help. I guess I should wait a while before I delete it, so someone can look at it. Cheers

Comment: You've only got one vote in favour of closing. Keep calm. And one downvote means nothing, I once had 30 downvotes for a question I posted, so relax.

Comment: In order to put **on hold** a question, five votes are necessary, you're still a long way from that happening. P.S I haven't read your question, but it's long and detailed, so it doesn't look like a low quality post. Just wait a couple of days, someone might post an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok, thanks. I just thought it meant that I had done something egregious. Cheers

Comment: I find your question on ELU crystal clear and upvoted it.  I find the reason for your having to ask the question less clear, but that just means I am more of a pragmatist than you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not worry so much about it next time. If you did anything *so bad* as to merit outright deletion of the question and profuse apologies, then it probably would have been flagged by the user and deleted for you for some major rules violation such as spam, rudeness or plagiarism. Also, keep in mind that if you want to delete a question, that you usually only have the option to do so before people start answering it, because de-publishing their answers on another person's whim usually is not fair.

Voting to close a question is different. Most of the time when people are voting to close it is for a minor infraction that is held against the question, rather than the questioner, and what we aim to do is to have any outstanding issues with the question fixed so that we can appropriately address it. You can read *[The War of the Closes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/)* for some information regarding the purpose of closure and what we hope for it to achieve. These sorts of minor infractions are only something that might be held against you if you showed a regular pattern of such infractions.

You should also note that Stack Exchange is not quite like other websites. Enforcement of the rules is typically a responsibility [which is communally shared by people](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) who have earned enough reputation points to have the requisite privileges. This can lead to some rather inconsistent enforcement in practice:

Some questions that should be closed remain open, and more relevantly some questions which should be open get closed, in which case there is an appeals proceedure. One vote to close is not indicative that you have actually violated any policies. The person who voted to close your question is not [a formal moderator](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators), or else the question would have been closed immediately rather than being left open for further peer review.

Indeed, the *one* vote to close you got so far was labeled as *"unclear what you are asking"*, and because you were observant of the Single Word Request requirement all that really means is that you have managed to confuse somebody regarding the nature of your problem. That could mean your post is genuinely confusing and should not be addressed until it is understandable, or it could mean that the voter lacks the cognitive skills to comprehend your post, which would not be your fault in any case.

I am not going to cast judgement one way or the other on that, but if it is your error, rather than the voter's, then you might want to see if there is anything you can do to make the post easier for other people to understand. It looks like you have already tried though, so there is not much to do other than wait and see if other posters agree with the closure rationale, or observe if the question has other defects which may merit a closure vote.

If the question is closed, you will get a message informing you as to what is wrong with the question and what you might try to do to get it reopened. You can also ask for advice regarding closed questions here on meta, as you seem to be aware.

You tried to do everything right from the onset though, so it should probably be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!